# netty client response mapping

Tags: websocket, netty

I have a netty **web socket server** running to which various native javascript clients connect. Now what I want to do is to get requests for data from the clients and pass back data according to what each client requested. There is a `class A` that actually needs to send continuous data asynchronously(ie: not a simple request reply model)to the client according to the request.

The question is - at class A , I have all the data that I need to send but how to figure out which data has to be sent to which client(has to be according to the client requests) , ie: how do I map the client requests , data to be sent from class A and the channel over which the data needs to be sent from class A. (I store all the channels in a `shared ChannelGroup`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try this.

1. Instance a [DefaultChannelGroup](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/group/DefaultChannelGroup.html): `DefaultChannelGroup myChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup("myChannels")`
2. When a web socket connect is established, add it to the channel group: `myChannels.add()`
3. Add the channel id and your request id to a hashmap
4. When you have data to write, I assume that you have the request id.  Use it to look up your channel id in the hashmap
5. Then get the channel from the channel group: `myCahnnels.find(channelId)`
6. Lastly, write the data to the channel.

Hope this helps.